# Joint PMF probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A particle starts at $(0,0)$ and moves in one-unit independent steps with equal probabilities of $\frac{1}{4}$ in each of the four directions: north,south,east and west. Let S equal to the east-west position and T the north-south position after three steps.

I know for this problem ,we have the sample space S={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} and T={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}.

When I saw the the solution, it has, for example,
P(S=-2,T=-1)=$\binom{3}{2} (\frac{1}{4})^3$= $\frac{3}{64}$

Something isn't clicking is I know $(\frac{1}{4})^3$ is the probability of three steps, I know $\binom{3}{2} $ is the the combinatorics of 2 steps of going in S(either west or east direction), when they multiply together, it doesn't make sense intuitively. What kind of distribution formula is that?

In addition, Let X=S+3 and Y=T+3, and find the marginal PMFs of X and Y, how am I supposed to do this? I am not sure X and Y meaning in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $E_{-2,-1} = \{S=-2,T=-1\}$ means that in the three steps you chose, one had to be down and two had to be to the left, in any order. So, the number of ways to choose the particular step when you went down was $\binom{3}{2}$.

At the same time, at each particular step, the probability of going down is $p_D = 1/4$, and the probability of going left is $p_L = 1/4$ each. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[E_{-2,-1}\right]
 = \binom{3}{2} \cdot p_D \cdot p_L^2
 = \binom{3}{2} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3
$$

---

To find the marginal PMFs of $X$ and $Y$, you can find their joint PMF using a similar construction to the one above, and then sum across one of the variables, which will give you the PMF of the other one.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the second question more? Do i have to recalculate the probability?